# Install zsh in Gentoo Prefix on Mountian Lion failed

Tags: zsh, gentoo

This is my first time to use gentoo prefix on Mac OS.

The installation of gentoo prefix took a while but all went well. I used this script to install gentoo prefix on Mac: http://overlays.gentoo.org/proj/alt/browser/trunk/prefix-overlay/scripts/bootstrap-prefix.sh?format=txt

However, when I was trying to install zsh, the compile of zsh kept failing.

The command I used is simply "emerge zsh", but I got the following error msg every time:

```
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in ~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/work/zsh-5.0.0 ...
make 
make[1]: Entering directory `~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/work/zsh-5.0.0/Src'
cd .. && ~/Gentoo/bin/bash $top_srcdir/Src/mkmakemod.sh Src Makemod
creating Src/Makemod.in
~/Gentoo/bin/bash: line 8: 42534 Illegal instruction: 4  ~/Gentoo/bin/bash $top_srcdir/Src/mkmakemod.sh Src Makemod
make[1]: *** [Makemod] Error 132
make[1]: Leaving directory `~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/work/zsh-5.0.0/Src'
make: *** [all] Error 1
 * ERROR: app-shells/zsh-5.0.0 failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=app-shells/zsh-5.0.0'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=app-shells/zsh-5.0.0'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/work/zsh-5.0.0'
 * S: '~/Gentoo/var/tmp/portage/app-shells/zsh-5.0.0/work/zsh-5.0.0'
```

Anyone knows the possible reason for this and how should I make it work?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Looks like wrong `CFLAGS` to me. What are you using?

Comment: Pastebin the build log and emerge --info ***or it didn't happen.***

Answer (score 0):

It seems that caused by bash.

in your .profile or .bashrc add the following:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I hope it goes well.